# maxlength attribute doesn't display when html is rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a textbox whose textmode is set to multiline.  Doing this renders the textbox as a textarea.  Something to this effect:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtFinBillingTerms" maxlength="500" runat="server" ToolTip="(e.g. 90/10, 30/30/30/10, etc.)" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="5" Rows="5" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>`

The issue I am having is when I run my project and inspect the textarea the rendered html does not show the maxlength attribute, its as if its gone:

rendered html:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$txtFinBillingTerms" rows="5" cols="5" id="MainContent_txtFinBillingTerms" title="(e.g. 90/10, 30/30/30/10, etc.)" style="width:300px;"></textarea>
```

This causes issues for me because I am trying to put in some javascript/jquery to limit input of my textarea, namely this:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
            var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
            alert(maxLength);
            if (e.which < 0x20) {
                // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
                // e.which === 0 - Not a character
                return;     // Do nothing
            }
            if (this.value.length == max) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (this.value.length > max) {
                // Maximum exceeded
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
            }
        });
```

But maxLength is always undefined....

Comment: You are using var maxLength but later in the code you only use max.

Comment: How can `e.which` be less that `0x20`? what are you trying to do here, `x` is not a multiplier, `*` is, but multiplying with zero always returns zero, so it's a bit unclear what the intention is ?

Comment: jeff mistake I'll have to fix that.  adeneo I am not trying to multiply here 0x20 is hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MaxLength` property isn't applicable for `<textarea>` so it's simply ignored. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This property is applicable only when the TextMode property is set to TextBoxMode.SingleLine or TextBoxMode.Password.

Lowercase `maxlength` attribute works on `<textarea>` but not all browsers supports it so it may depends on that or how ASP.NET will handle that property (it doesn't support it so it may simply remove that attribute).

**Edit:** You can workaround this limitation using some JavaScript or a validation control with this expression: `ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,500}$"` (code from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/40065.aspx?TextBox%20MultiLine%20maxlength)). If you want to perform only client-side validation then you have at least these options:

1) Use a different name for that attribute (like `data-maxlength`) both in your ASP.NET page and in your JavaScript:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFinBillingTerms"
    data-maxlength="500"
    ToolTip="(e.g. 90/10, 30/30/30/10, etc.)"
    TextMode="MultiLine"
    Columns="5" Rows="5" Width="300px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

With:

```
var maxLength = $(this).data('maxlength');
```

2) If you don't use directly your `<asp:Input>` control in your ASP.NET code then you may use a `<textarea runat="server">` instead of *official* ASP.NET control, like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<textarea runat="server" ID="txtFinBillingTerms"
    maxlength="500"
    title="(e.g. 90/10, 30/30/30/10, etc.)"
    cols="5" rows="5" style="width: 300px">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Well spotted, `TextMode="MultiLine"` creates a textarea.

Comment: Even if I use `maxlength` this doesnt work properly.  So what does one need to do here?

Comment: @JonH edited. A possible workaround is to use a validation control.

Comment: Adriano Im not sure I get what you mean, I want to make this as reusable as possible, I may have 5 textarea's on a page on various pages, so i wanted something generic in my site.master file that would handle this.  I dont want serverside validation controls for all these textareas, and the issue I have is some textareas have different max lengths then others.  Isn't there a standard way of doing this which allows me to grab the maxlength of a textarea in jquery for any browser?

Comment: @JonH just use another name for that attribute, sadly it's managed by ASP.NET input so it's ignored for textarea. You may use a custom attribute (data-) or directly a textarea with runat="server".